# Looping through Dataframe to delete "near duplicate" rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have a dataframe and would like to get rid of rows where a particular column has matching values to subsequent values. An example can be found below:

Original Data Frame:

| ID | Cat1 | Cat2 | Cat3 | Averages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 8 | SWE | 220.90 |
| 2 | 8 | 8 | SWE | 249.14 |
| 3 | SWE | SWE | SWE | 358.54 |
| 4 | DR | DR | DR | 204.41 |
| 5 | SWE | SWE | SWE | 354.08 |
| 6 | Eng | Eng | Eng | 212.14 |
| 7 | HTE | HTE | HTE | 220.04 |
| 8 | 8 | SWE | SWE | 220.90 |
| 9 | 8 | SWE | SWE | 249.14 |
| 10 | 4 | Apple | Apple | 296.04 |
| 11 | 4 | Grape | Grape | 336.52 |
| 12 | 3 | Apple | Apple | 768.01 |
| 13 | 5 | Peach | Peach | 519.90 |
| 14 | NBS | Apple | Apple | 525.58 |
| 15 | Staff | BBQ | BBQ | 326.25 |
| 16 | BP | Pear | Pear | 262.11 |
| 17 | PM | Pear | Pear | 469.20 |
| 18 | Marketing | Banana | Banana | 206.75 |
| 19 | SWE | Grape | Grape | 400.28 |
| 20 | SWE | Barley | Barley | 321.63 |

I'd like to ignore any rows where the Averages column value has already occurred. For instance, ID 1 and ID 8 have the same Averages value. So I would like to remove the ID 8 row from the table. Another occurrence are the row with ID 2 and ID 9, they have the same Averages value so I'd eliminate the row with ID 9 from the table. My end output would then be:

| ID | Cat1 | Cat2 | Cat3 | Averages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 8 | SWE | 220.90 |
| 2 | 8 | 8 | SWE | 249.14 |
| 3 | SWE | SWE | SWE | 358.54 |
| 4 | DR | DR | DR | 204.41 |
| 5 | SWE | SWE | SWE | 354.08 |
| 6 | Eng | Eng | Eng | 212.14 |
| 7 | HTE | HTE | HTE | 220.04 |
| 10 | 4 | Apple | Apple | 296.04 |
| 11 | 4 | Grape | Grape | 336.52 |
| 12 | 3 | Apple | Apple | 768.01 |
| 13 | 5 | Peach | Peach | 519.90 |
| 14 | NBS | Apple | Apple | 525.58 |
| 15 | Staff | BBQ | BBQ | 326.25 |
| 16 | BP | Pear | Pear | 262.11 |
| 17 | PM | Pear | Pear | 469.20 |
| 18 | Marketing | Banana | Banana | 206.75 |
| 19 | SWE | Grape | Grape | 400.28 |
| 20 | SWE | Barley | Barley | 321.63 |

I've tried to do for loops to do this, but when I do a for loop on the data frame, it lops through the columns and not the rows. Any help here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

By default it uses all columns to identify the duplicated rows:

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

To limit to a subset of columns:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Averages'])
```